# Optical Character Recognition (OCR) Tool to Convert Pictures or Images to Text

Tags: software-recommendation, ocr, text

I have scanned text. I am looking for an affordable OCR tool (Optical Character Recognition) tool. I tried OCRTOOLS from the App Store, but it crashes with the first picture I tried.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Google Docs, it has OCR built in.

When you're uploading something, just check the
 `Convert text from PDF or image files to Google Docs documents`
option.

You can download Google Docs files as whatever format you want.

Comment: I've tried google docs and an other App from the store (OCR Kit): They're both terrible (in terms of what they recognize)

Comment: I've made the best results with a $4.00 iPhone App called Perfect OCR.

Answer (score 3):

Are you comfortable on the command line? If you have `fink` or `macports` installed, then you can easily install [gocr](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) or [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). I've had some success with each of these. Note that tesseract is, I think, the tool that Google uses for their book scanning.

For tesseract, images must be in TIF format and have extension TIF or tif (one F, not two).

Adobe tools also have effective and built-in OCR, as far as I know, but I have never used them.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for several months and felt that I needed an intuitive and elegant workflow for OCR. I hated the terminal solutions and to make sure I put in the right format. I wanted something I would love to use. This drove me to creating to following App:
[image: Condense Logo]

You may find more information here: [www.condenseapp.com](http://www.condenseapp.com)